# How to return the sum of two computed observable?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm not really familiar with KnockoutJS but I'm trying to get the sum of two computed observable and bind it to a table:

I have this:

```
var cost = ko.computed(function () {
        total = 0;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(claimTreatments(), function (item) {
            total += item.Cost;
        })
        return total;
    });
```

And,

```
 var amount = ko.computed(function () {
        total = 0;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(claimDrugs(), function (item) {
            total += item.Drugcost;
        })
        return total;
    });
```

And I'm trying something like this but not working.

```
var totalamount = ko.computed(function () {
        total = cost() + amount();
        return total;
    });
```

Also this is a picture of the table I'm trying to bind it to(the Amount field), to give a clear idea of the scenario[image: that's the table I'm trying to bind to]

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle showing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just minor fixes will do the trick here use `self` . If you want to bind it to view . `var` is quite local to viewModel view doesn't quite recognize it .

**viewModel:**

```
var claimDrugs = [{'Drugcost':10},{'Drugcost':10},{'Drugcost':10}
]

claimTreatments  = [{'Cost':10},{'Cost':10},{'Cost':10}
]

var ViewModel = function() {
var self=this;    
self.cost = ko.computed(function () {
        total = 0;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(claimTreatments, function (item) {
            total += item.Cost;
        })
        return total;
    });

   self.amount = ko.computed(function () {
        total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(claimDrugs, function (item) {
            total += item.Drugcost;
        })
        return total;
    });

    self.totalamount = ko.computed(function () {
        total = self.cost() + self.amount();
        return total;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

**View :**

```
<div >   
    <p> <label data-bind='text: cost' ></label></p> 
    <p> <label data-bind='text: amount' ></label></p> 
    <h2><label data-bind='text: totalamount'> </label></h2>  
</div>
```

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24786/)**

**PS:** yes indeed you can add two computed the way you doing but binding to view you use above approach .

Comment: thanks @supercool! quick question, why isn't the (var) working? i used it a bunch in my code and they worked fine!

Comment: var will work fine to add computed but to show it in view its not gonna help it . check the above edits

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Knockout >= 3.2.0 you should also consider using [pureComputed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) instead of `Computed`.